# Obtaining the Netbean's arguments of java compiling process (step by step)

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

I made my project using Netbeans 8.0, my project (my-project.jar) works fine, but I want to replicate compiling process through MS-DOS CLI, like:

**STEP 1:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac.exe" -encoding utf8 -cp .;C:\pack1.jar;C:\pack2.jar -d D:\...\classes D:\...\src\my\project\*.java
```

But' I noticed that *the size* of generated classes in this form *are different* to generated by Netbeans,

**STEP 2**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\jar.exe" cvfm0 "D:\...\dist\my-project.jar" "d:\...\MANIFEST.MF" -C D:\...\classes my\project
```

I was reviewing the tree of classes, Manifest and Compresion is same (CLI is equal to Netbeans)

**STEP 3**
Test my project (package generated using CLI) in the same way I tried my same project (package generated using Netbeans).

*The result was failed!*

**QUESTION**: I need the command line (with arguments) that Netbeans performs the compilation.

**NOTE**: I was reviewing the *project.properties* and *build-impl.xml* files, I need to print the lines command with arguments when the above mentioned files are being executed.

Comment: Why? Use Ant or Maven like everybody else does, including Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your project from command line using Ant - by default NetBeans projects use Ant as their build-tool. You can install Ant or use the copy bundled into NetBeans installation.

If you really want to see how it is compiled and call `javac` on your own then set the verbosity level of Ant output to **verbose** and re-run the build. You can do this when you click on *Ant settings* button in top left bar of build output or use menu `Tools | Option | Java | Ant` (formerly it was in `Tools | Option | Miscellaneous | Ant`)

Answer (score 0):

You can to change settings ant, like `@Radim` answer..., or change it In Output window (tools Icon).

Looks for `Compilation arguments` and you will obtain the compilation arguments like this:

```
Using modern compiler
Compilation arguments:
'-d'
'D:\...\build\classes'
'-classpath'
'D:\...\build\classes;C:\pack1.jar;C:\pack2.jar'
'-sourcepath'
'D:\...\build\empty'
'-target'
'1.7'
'-encoding'
'UTF-8'
'-g'
'-processorpath'
'C:\pack1.jar;C:\pack2.jar;D:\...\build\empty'
'-s'
'D:\...\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output'
'-source'
'1.7'
```